# Labeling vertical and horizontal axis

Tags: tikz-pgf

I need to add "Title A" and Title B" in the following cartesian diagram:

[image]

I have used the following code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.16}
\usepgfplotslibrary{statistics}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1]
\draw[dotted] (-3.1,-2.1) grid (3.1,2.1);


\draw[<->] (-3.1,0)node[left] {labe1}  -- (3.1,0) node[right] {label2};

\draw[<->] (0,-2.1)node[below] {label3} -- (0,2.1) node[above] {label4};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**as follows**

```tex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.16}
\usepgfplotslibrary{statistics}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1]
\draw[dotted] (-3.1,-2.1) grid (3.1,2.1);


\draw[<->] (-3.1,0)node[left] {labe1}  -- (3.1,0) node[right] {label2};

\draw[<->] (0,-2.1)node[below] {label3} -- (0,2.1) node[above] {label4};

%% as follows

\node[rotate=90,font=\bfseries] at (-4.5,0){TitleB};
\node[font=\bfseries] at (0,3.5){TitleA};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]